# MySQL - Insert into a table by querying product id from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.

Here is the structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT` 
  ( 
     `CATEGORY_ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Category ID', 
     `PRODUCT_ID`  INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Product ID', 
     `POSITION`    INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Position', 
     PRIMARY KEY (`CATEGORY_ID`, `PRODUCT_ID`), 
     KEY `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID` (`PRODUCT_ID`) 
  ) 
ENGINE=INNODB 
DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 
COMMENT='Catalog Product To Category Linkage Table'; 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TIER_PRICE` 
  ( 
     `VALUE_ID`          INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Value ID', 
     `ENTITY_ID`         INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 
     'Entity ID', 
     `ALL_GROUPS`        SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 
     'Is Applicable To All Customer Groups', 
     `CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 
     'Customer Group ID', 
     `QTY`               DECIMAL(12, 4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.0000' COMMENT 'QTY', 
     `VALUE`             DECIMAL(12, 4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000' COMMENT 
     'Value', 
     `WEBSITE_ID`        SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Website ID', 
     PRIMARY KEY (`VALUE_ID`) 
  ) 
ENGINE=INNODB 
DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 
COMMENT='Catalog Product Tier Price Attribute Backend Table';
```

So I have around 500 products.

I queried the product ids from the `catalog_category_product` where `category_id = 37`

This is the query.

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID 
FROM   `CATALOG_CATEGORY_PRODUCT` 
WHERE  CATEGORY_ID = 37
```

Using that result I would like to insert the price into tier price table.

```
INSERT INTO `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TIER_PRICE` 
            (`ENTITY_ID`, 
             `ALL_GROUPS`, 
             `CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID`, 
             `QTY`, 
             `VALUE`, 
             `WEBSITE_ID`) 
VALUES      (209, 
             1, 
             0, 
             60.0000, 
             10.0000, 
             0);
```

Here `catalog_product_entity_tier_price.entity_id = catalog_category_product.product_id`

So 209 is the first result of `catalog_category_product` query. I would like to do the same thing for all results.

Can someone help me with mysql query to accomplish that?

Comment: Where does the values for the other columns  `qty`, `value`, `website_id` come from?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal They are the same for all rows.

Comment: How does one purchase a fraction of a product?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but what happens when the price of a product changes?

Comment: @DanBracuk My client actually has the same price for all products. Its just tier price. price will be $10 when they purchase 60+ products.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` like this:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`, 
                                                 `all_groups`, 
                                                 `customer_group_id`,
                                                  `qty`, 
                                                  `value`, 
                                                  `website_id`)
SELECT product_id, 1, 0, 60.0000, 10.0000, 0
FROM `catalog_category_product`
WHERE category_id =37
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do an [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`, `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `value`, `website_id`) 
SELECT product_id, 1, 0, 60.0000, 10.0000, 0 
  FROM `catalog_category_product`
  WHERE category_id =37
```

This would insert one row per result of your `SELECT` query. All  other columns would be the same in all inserted rows.

If you want other values in the other columns, you would have to specify them someway.